# OpenCV 3.0.0 with extra modules - imgproc dependency

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have downloaded the latest master-branches of opencv 3.0 and the extra modules from itseez's github. Following the instructions for compiling opencv 3.0 with modules, I used the following command line on Ubuntu 14.04

```
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/.../opencv-3.0.0-beta/opencv_contrib-master/modules /home/.../opencv-3.0.0-beta
```

where 1st path leads to modules folder and the 2nd one leads to opencv 3 sources.

Among other errors/warnings I am especially concerned with this one

```
-- Module opencv_tracking disabled because opencv_imgproc dependency can't be resolved!
```

since I am most interested in tracking module. Is there any way to help the  cmake resolve this dependency? Extensive googling yielded no answer and I am not a linux compilation guru either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved by moving on and cloning the pure latest master of both  opencv 3 and contrib. Previously I downloaded them as zip.